# Doctrine Query, association ManyToOne

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I have 2 entities:

```
Class A {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(...)
     */
    private $b;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;
}

Class B {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(...)
     */
    private $a;

}
```

Need a Query for get all entities "B" that yours "A" have all dates "date" below to date that I set as parameter.

Now have these Query, but is no result:

> "SELECT b FROM Entity:B b INNER JOIN b.a a WHERE a.date > :date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following :

```
public function myfunction($date){
    $dql = "SELECT b FROM Entity:B as b WHERE b.a IN (".
               "SELECT a.id FROM Entity:A as a WHERE a.date > :date".
           ")";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameter('date', $date)
    ;

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

I tested on some of my entities that have similar structure and it works

Comment: Glad I could help! I lost a bunch lot of hours on a problem that was closely the same!